# Crashes are shown in developer console

Tags: android

I have recently submitted app to playstore. I think app is tested automatically by Google devices. I found many crashes (around 70) in Play store developer console. When i have tested in my real devices, i haven't get any crashes. How to avoid the crashes/remove the crashes from the list by the next time.

My app has login, without login user, user can't go to the dashboard. But the crash reports are related to within the app(I mean after the login).

How to handle this scenario ? Do we need to write any test cases to avoid such crashes from google devices since we are not getting crashes.
`

```
@Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                if (CropMainActivity.cropped == null) {
                    return "";
                }
                return compress(CropMainActivity.cropped);
            }




java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:254)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.myapp.fragment.MyProfileFragment.compress(MyProfileFragment.java:250)
  at com.myapp.fragment.MyProfileFragment.access$100(MyProfileFragment.java:51)
  at com.myapp.fragment.MyProfileFragment$2.doInBackground(MyProfileFragment.java:185)
  at com.myapp.fragment.MyProfileFragment$2.doInBackground(MyProfileFragment.java:181)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

`
[image]

Comment: That you did not found any crashes in your real device, does not automatically mean, there are no crashes in the wild. Why not fixing them instead of trying to "hide"em.?

Comment: The automatic tests from google cannot log in, so your story is a bit weird. `But the crash reports are related to within the app(I mean after the login).` How are you able to get crashes after the login when the google devices cannot log in?

Comment: See the answer of CommonsWare below.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re We have done manually testing here. We havent face these issues. If code is not okay, that should reproducible for us right ?

Comment: "We have done manually testing".. Sure, but that does NOT guarantee that you just did not find your bugs. I bet you're not using all kinds of brands, all kinds of android versions and are aware of every possible way to get around your login. If you do not agree, okay, I am simply telling you the same as commensware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to avoid the crashes/remove the crashes from the list by the next time.

Analyze the stack traces, try to identify the bugs, then fix the bugs. Ship an update to your app with the bug fixes.

Then, as the legendary shampoo bottle instructions read, "lather, rinse, repeat", as you will encounter this same sort of problem in the future, most likely.

> I think app is tested automatically by Google devices.

It does not really matter whether the crashes come from ordinary users, from some sort of automated testing engine, or from a ferret hopped up on crystal meth. If your app is crashing in the field, there is a bug in your app. If nothing else, you are missing some defensive programming steps that would detect the problem before crashing, then redirect the user somewhere else.

> My app has login, without login user, user can't go to the dashboard.

Perhaps the bug in your app is that there are ways to get to the dashboard without logging in. For example, perhaps the dashboard activity has an `<intent-filter>` or is otherwise exported, meaning that anyone, at any time, can start that activity. Or, perhaps the dashboard activity assumes certain `static` fields will be populated, which might not be the case, if the app's process was terminated while it was in the background.

Comment: thank you very much. I have updated the log. Method has already null check. why still we are getting crash ?

Comment: @AndroidDeveloperWorld: Since nobody knows what line 250 inside `MyProfileFragment.java` is, nobody can really help you with that. In general, your `null` check may not be effective, as you are apparently in a multi-threading situation (your `null` check appears to be in `doInBackground()` of an `AsyncTask`). What happens if another thread sets this `static` field to `null` between the `null` check and your use of that field?

Comment: Okay,I would agree that might have some code issues. But  how is possible to test the flow without providing data by me. Since my api calls are required mobile number/login  as parameter and that should be in my server(mobile number). I have seen that in Apple store, we need to provide to dummy credentials to test the app by Apple team. Is there something in Playstore. When we test manually after login with right credentials, everything is fine. Otherwise we could get the same error that google playstore gets.

Comment: @AndroidDeveloperWorld: "But how is possible to test the flow without providing data by me" -- I do not know your app. I have no way to comment on this.

Comment: okay, thanks for the input. My app is : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ytrtech.waltairclub